# Added wcf service operations but they did not generate Properties/database files

Tags: wcf

I added new service operations, just like the others, which are working,
using [OperationContract] attribute.

I noticed however that all the operations I cannot see in the client object (these that I am trying to add right now) are all missing their counterpart .database generated files within Properties, in the solution explorer.

I am not sure this is the reason why I cannot see the newly added operations, but it's the only relation I could find between the non-visible and visible operations in the client.

What I found searching for a similar problem is using OperationContractAttribute instead, but it does not help me.

Comment: If you're using a host reference (either the URL or .svc file), you have to delete the previous reference and re-add the changed host reference if your additions are to show up in your project.

Comment: My WCF service is a .svc file that sits in a WCF Service Project. I did several times delete and add the service reference to the project that is using it, but to no avail. While I have no serious knowledge in WCF, my team does, and they have been trying to help with this issue all the day long. And we did not come to any solution yet.